# How to create a clear button in php

Tags: php, button

I am new to PHP and am having trouble with this code. I want to be able to press the "clear files" button and have all of the specified columns for my ID row in my database become null.

One file contains this code:

```
function deleteFiles()
{
    $sql="UPDATE apps 
          SET fileName= null, 
              urlName = null, 
              formKey = null 
          WHERE appID='".$ID."'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
}
```

In another file that is connected to the previous file, this code is listed:

```
if (isset($ID))
{
    echo '<form action="../apps" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onclick"return deleteFiles()"">';

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="clear" value="'.$ID.'" />';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Clear Files" style="margin-right: 5px;" />';

    echo '</form>';
}
```

I'm not quite sure what is wrong with my code.

Comment: Can you tell me what happen with your current code?

Comment: Where are you setting $ID within the deleteFiles() function

Comment: You seem to be mixing JavaScript and PHP.  `onclick="return deleteFiles()"` is going to try to execute a *JavaScript* function called `deleteFiles()`, not a *PHP* function.  (Also, a `form` shouldn't have a meaningful "onclick" event.  "onsubmit" maybe, but not "onclick".)

Comment: $ID is set within the second file. Its just a variable

Comment: You have a variable scope issue - http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php. You need to add `$ID` to your function parameter - `function deleteFiles($ID)` and function call `deleteFiles($_POST['clear'])`. Also, you need to escape the data as you are open to SQL injection.

Comment: It does not work like that. The function is it's own encapsulated block of code, unless you pass the variable to it `function deleteFiles($ID)`, define it as global `global $ID` or it is a super global like `$_POST`, the function knows nothing about it.

Comment: Javascript runs on the client. PHP runs on the server. You cannot directly invoke one language's functions from others, because they're never running in the same place at the same time.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest reading up on SQL injection. If you continue with your current pattern, you'll be very vulnerable to that. As a general rule, never, *ever* pass unsanitized parameters from a web request directly into an SQL query. See here for more info: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php13p5.html

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is invoke a PHP function from Javascript method. Try using ajax. Most suitable link is [AJAX](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&ved=0CFUQFjAC&url=http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/&ei=u07tUbmLLYinrAfWg4HYAg&usg=AFQjCNF1ITsE5bJBc65MY4nqhZq7OkHZpg&sig2=ulpVlNErxWMQhAUVu7aVTw&bvm=bv.49478099,d.bmk).

I would have wrote this in comment but I do not have enough credits to do so.

Answer (score 0):

To access the `$ID` variable, you need to use `$_POST['ID']`.  You will use this in the form and the SQL query.

Make sure to pass that variable into your function so the function can "see" the `$ID` variable.

```
function deleteFiles($ID) {
    // All your code
}

// Call the function
deletefiles($_POST['ID']);
```

Lastly, instead of making the rows `NULL`, why not use a `DELETE` query.  Check the docs out here: [MySQL DELETE Query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html).